# https embeded You tube video is not playing in website

Tags: php, video, youtube

I have created a youtube video. And then I embed that in my web application which is in PHP. But that video is not working on my site even it's playing on youtube. Other videos are working there when I change iframe src to any other video. Here is link to my site. Please click here : http://highpointtax.ca/dev/ Video is part of Macbook.

Please help. I am on deadline.

Cheers!!

Comment: If you view the developer console you get an error `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYvN7o-e7_8' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`. I suspect you haven't enabled embedding in the video options on Youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just copy the page URL and stick it in an iframe. If that worked it would still have the rest of the YouTube page around it. On YouTube click 'Share' -> 'Embed' and copy the embed code it gives you:

```
<iframe width="497" height="313" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YYvN7o-e7_8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```